# LinkedinAPI: Get Phone Number from 1st Connection?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I've tried 
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,phone-numbers)
but it's only get (id,first-name,last-name)

even this: 
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=UserId:(phone-numbers)

Does LinkedIn expose this field ? I've google it, but not found somewhere ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linkedin Not provide phone numbers of connections. They only provide basic profile of connections.
 check here https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn will provide the phone number if the user authorizes `r_contactinfo`

**Sample Request URL:**

> [https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,***phone-numbers***)?format=json](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,phone-numbers)?format=json)

**Sample JSON Response:**

```
{
  "id": "ye3i9-_24l",
  "phoneNumbers":  {
    "_total": 1,
    "values":  [
       {
        "phoneNumber": "89xx189198",
        "phoneType": "mobile"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn not provide phone number. Check this document for accessible fields of profile
[Basic Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)